# How do I Implement a Circular Reference in Entity Core Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am trying to store a set of nodes that have references to other nodes using Entity Framework Core. Each node can reference X number of nodes. Let's use the following graph as an example.

[image: Example Node Setup]

Below is a map of which nodes go with.

A -> B

B -> C

C -> B

C -> A

C -> D

D -> C

Here is my setup in Entity Framework Core. I am using a List of Locations

```
public class Location
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

I then map A to B. Everything goes well. But when I try to reference B to A it produces a circular reference error. Here a and b are both Location types.

```
a.Locations.Add(b);
context.SaveChanges();

b.Locations.Add(a);
context.SaveChanges();  // Circular Reference Error Here
```

I think using the Fluent API holds the key. I've tried the following but that leads to an error about a missing key but I don't have a way to add a key. Here is my attempt.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Location>(e =>
 {
     e.HasMany(l => l.Locations)
         .WithMany(l => l.Locations);
 });
```

How do I implement a circular many to many relationship as described?

Comment: Looks like you need a many-to-many join table. With both the parent and child being the same type. Though EF Core 5 can generate that table without requiring a new class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: @JeremyLakeman - I followed the article and created the many-to-many but it leads to the same key error found below.

The entity type 'WorldLocationWorldLocation (Dictionary<string, object>)' requires a primary key to be defined.

Here is the new model building portion.

`entity.HasMany(l => l.ConnectedLocations).WithMany(l => l.ConnectedLocations).UsingEntity(m => m.ToTable("LocationMap"));`

Any ideas?

Comment: Think about all the types and navigation properties you would need to define for a `type 1 <= many => type 2` relationship. Just because type 1 and type 2 are the same type, doesn't mean that you can merge the navigations together.